# Execve with argument in x64 with gnu asm

Tags: assembly, arguments, x86-64, shellcode, execv

I am trying to write a shellcode in GNU asm for linux and i'm unable to call execve with arguments.

What i'm trying to do :

```
execve("/bin/ls", ["/bin/ls", "-la", NULL], NULL);
```

this is my code :

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    push $0x3b
    pop %rax
    xorq %rdx,%rdx
    
    push %rdx
    movabs $0x61616161616c2d2d,%r8
    shr $0x8, %r8
    push %r8
    
    movabs $0x736c2f6e69622f2f,%r8
    shr $0x8, %r8                    
    push   %r8
    mov    %rsp,  %rdi
    push   %rdx
    push   %rdi
    mov    %rsp,  %rsi
    syscall
    
    push $0x3c
    pop %rax
    xorq    %rdi,  %rdi
    syscall
```

And just before the syscall to execv this are my reg/stack :
[gdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xztSp.png)

I suppose that :
RDI must contain "/bin/ls" address
RSI must contain the address of the "/bin/ls" address
RDX = NULL

the shellcode is executing /bin/ls but not with -la args.

What is wrong ?

thx

Comment: The arguments are a C style array, pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never pushed a pointer to the second argv string.  `push %rdx; push %rdi` pushes NULL and then the pointer to `"/bin/ls"`, but there is no pointer to your `"-laaaaa"`.  You need one more `push` in between the two.  For instance:

```
    push %rdx           // NULL
    lea 8(%rdi), %rcx   // pointer to "-laaaaa"
    push %rcx
    push %rdi           // pointer to "/bin/ls"
    mov %rsp, %rsi      // pointer to the argument vector
```